# Corregir este problema de código en C sobre un juego de equipos de futbol

Tags: c

estoy buscando que las variables puntajeA, puntajeB, puntajeC, puntajeD sumen +3
cada vez que ''X'' equipo gane, cualquiera de los 4 equipos, y si quedan empatados que también sume un +3, no he podido lograr esto y al final me arroja números no esperados, quisiera saber si alguien puede comentarme los errores que tengo y yo poder tratar de corregirlos.

Al principio cuando compila me va diciendo quienes son los equipos que van ganando correctamente, obviamente utilizando el sistema de números random, estos pueden quedar empatados o uno le gana al otro, sucede que quiero que las variables puntajes, cada vez que ocurra un empate o gane un equipo, vaya sumando un +3 a su equipo, esto es algo que no puedo lograr y quisiera saber si alguien podría corregir algún error, aunque bueno, suelo tener demasiados, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

char nEquipoA[15]; //Nombre de el equipo A
char nEquipoB[15]; //Nombre de el equipo B
char nEquipoC[15]; //Nombre de el equipo C
char nEquipoD[15]; //Nombre de el equipo D


int suma(puntos){
    puntos = puntos + 3;
    return puntos;
}
    
int final(final1,final2,final3,final4){ //Funcion final, va a printear los resultados de la variable puntaje 3 + 3 dependiendo si gana o pierde.
printf("%d , %d , %d , %d",final1,final2,final3,final4);
Sleep(5000);
}

int goles(Equipo1,Equipo2,cGoles1,cGoles2,puntaje1,puntaje2){ //Esta funcion me va a decir la cantidad de goles que anota cierto equipo
srand(time(NULL));

cGoles1 = rand()%5;
printf("La cantidad de goles del equipo %s son %d \n",Equipo1, cGoles1);


cGoles2 = rand()%5;
printf("La cantidad de goles del equipo %s son %d \n",Equipo2, cGoles2);

if(cGoles1>cGoles2){                                 //Aca es donde entra el puntaje, pido que si un equipo anota mas goles que el otro, se suma su variable de puntaje.
    printf("El ganador es %s \n",Equipo1);
          suma(puntaje1);
          return puntaje1;
       }
       
else if(cGoles1<cGoles2){
    printf("El ganador es %s \n",Equipo2);          // Aca ahora es al reves, significa que el equipo 2 suma un + 3 a su puntaje
          suma(puntaje2);
          return puntaje1;
      }
else if(cGoles1==cGoles2){
    printf("Ambos equipos quedan en empate \n");
            // Aqui dice que si los dos quedan en empate, entonces puntaje se suma + 3 de todas formas.
      
    }
    
    
}
   
    
int main(){

printf("Esto es el mundial de futbol, consta de 1 grupo de 4 equipos. \n"); //Elige los nombres de los equipos
Sleep(1000);

printf("Ingresa el nombre del primer equipo \n");
  scanf("%s", &nEquipoA);
  printf("Ingresa el nombre del segundo equipo \n");
  scanf("%s", &nEquipoB);
  printf("Ingresa el nombre del tercer equipo \n");
  scanf("%s", &nEquipoC);
  printf("Ingresa el nombre del cuarto equipo \n");
  scanf("%s", &nEquipoD);
  eleccion(nEquipoA,nEquipoB,nEquipoC,nEquipoD);
}

int eleccion(Equipo1,Equipo2,Equipo3,Equipo4){ //Esto es el bucle del juego, va a ir declarando quien va ganando o perdiendo.
int i=1;
int EquipoA, EquipoB, EquipoC, EquipoD;
int puntajeA, puntajeB, puntajeC,puntajeD; //VARIABLES DE PUNTAJE DE ESTA FUNCION

while (i <= 7){
    system("cls");
if(i==1){
printf("Va a jugar el equipo %s , contra el equipo %s \n",Equipo1,Equipo2);
        goles(Equipo1,Equipo2,EquipoA,EquipoB,puntajeA,puntajeB);
        i++;
        Sleep(5000);
        system("cls");
}
if(i==2){
    printf("Va a jugar el equipo %s, contra el equipo %s \n",Equipo1,Equipo3);
    goles(Equipo1,Equipo3,EquipoA,EquipoC,puntajeA,puntajeC);
    i++;
    Sleep(5000);
    system("cls");
}
if(i==3){
    printf("Va a jugar el equipo %s, contra el equipo %s \n", Equipo1,Equipo4);
    goles(Equipo1,Equipo4,EquipoA,EquipoD,puntajeA,puntajeD);
    i++;
    Sleep(5000);
    system("cls");
   }
   if(i==4){
    printf("Va a jugar el equipo %s, contra el equipo %s \n", Equipo2, Equipo3);
    goles(Equipo2,Equipo3,EquipoB,EquipoC,puntajeB,puntajeC);
    i++;
    Sleep(5000);
    system("cls");
   }
   if(i==5){
    printf("Va a jugar el equipo %s, contra el equipo %s \n", Equipo2, Equipo4);
    goles(Equipo2,Equipo4,EquipoB,EquipoD,puntajeB,puntajeD);
    i++;
    Sleep(5000);
    system("cls");
   }
   if(i==6){
    printf("Va a jugar el equipo %s, contra el equipo %s \n", Equipo3,Equipo4);
    goles(Equipo3,Equipo4,EquipoC,EquipoD,puntajeC,puntajeD);
    Sleep(5000);
    system("cls");
    i++;
   } 
   if(i==7){
    final(puntajeA,puntajeB,puntajeC,puntajeD); //Esta función me va a mandar hacía el final, donde me deberia printear el resultado de los puntajes.
    i++;
   }
}
}
    ```
````

Comment: Los puntajes no se te actualizan porque no los pasas a las funciones por referencia.

Comment: El programa no compila. No hay por donde cogerlo. Por ejemplo, no defines los tipos de las variables en los parámetros de la función. Consigue que el código, al menos, compile antes de editar tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Si compila, depende del compilador y hasta medio funciona.

Comment: Elias, pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Tu pregunta y sus potenciales respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros quienes tengan un problema similar. Tu pregunta será difícil de encontrar si se titula "pueden corregirme este código". Además, recuerda que en [es.so] se responde a preguntas _concretas_.

Comment: @Francisco No es algo que dependa del compilador sino del estándar ... para que eso pase hay que remontarse a estándares anteriores a C99 ... y hace 23 años de dicho estándar ya ... lo siento pero no.

Ese código ya no puede ser considerado C válido

Comment: A mi me compilo(con gcc) con un montón de warnig eso si, y entiende que son parámetros enteros al no poner el tipo. Con g++ da error en esos puntos

Comment: El hecho de usar un if para cada valor posible de `i` hace que el ciclo sea innecesario. La función de los ciclos es reducir el código necesario para hacer una tarea repetitiva. Ahora mismo es mejor que quites los if, el while y escribas las instrucciones una después de la otra simplemente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicializa los puntajes para que veas que no cambian:

```
int puntajeA=0, puntajeB=0, puntajeC=0,puntajeD=0;
```

Luego o ejecuta una simulación de mundialito. Verás que todos salen a cero.

Pasa los parametros a la función goles para que actualize el puntaje.

```
int goles(char *Equipo1,char *Equipo2,int cGoles1,int cGoles2,int *puntaje1,int *puntaje2){
//Esta funcion me va a decir la cantidad de goles que anota cierto equipo
```

Y llama correctamente a la función goles pasando las direcciones de memoria de las variables. El operador [`&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of) sirve para obtenerla. Por ejemplo:

```
goles(Equipo1, Equipo2, EquipoA, EquipoB, &puntajeA, &puntajeB);
```

Cambiar la función suma para que reciba un puntero:

```
int suma(int *puntos){
    *puntos += 3;
    return puntos;
}
```

Luego o ejecuta una simulación de mundialito y verás que se actualiza el puntaje.

Finalmente, añadir el caso de los empates:

```
suma(puntaje1);
suma(puntaje2); 
//Aquí dice que si los dos quedan en empate, entonces suma + 3 de todas formas.
```

**Nota:**
Hay una [conversión implícita](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Array_to_pointer_conversion) de arreglos a punteros. Por ejemplo los `nEquipoX` no necesitas usar el operador `&`. Ejemplo:

```
scanf("%s", nEquipoA);
```

Comment: Si el código ni siquiera compila ... ¿cómo va a ejecutarlo?

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! pude resolver el ejercicio con la ayuda de todos ustedes, he aprendido a tener en cuenta que debo definir los tipos de variables al llamarlos a una función y voy tomando en cuenta las veces que debería usar un ciclo, en este caso era algo muy innecesario, muchas gracias igualmente por la explicación Mateo y Francisco, esto me enseñó bastante sobre el operador & y los punteros, ya sé para aplicarlos más adelante.